# Is there any ways I can download Google Chrome 32 bit deb file for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, chrome, 32bit

Where can I download Google Chrome for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS 32 bit?

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome is no longer supported on 32-bit Linux or any architecture of Ubuntu 12.04/Debian 7.

You can install it, but it is not a good idea. It gets no security updates, and is currently vulnerable to many security bugs. You also don't get any new features.

There are a few things you can do, though.

- If you really want to use Google Chrome, it may be time to get a 64-bit capable computer.
- If you can't get a new computer, try out Chromium. It's pretty much Chrome, but open-source and upheld by the community. Install it by running:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
  ```
- If you don't care very much about Chrome vs. other browsers, you can just use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Google [discontinued](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/FoE6sL-p6oU) 32-bit builds. Given that Chrome is closed-source, there can't be any unofficial builds.

However, Chromium, the core of Google Chrome, is open-source and will keep supporting i386 (as per link above).  It's available in Xenial under the name of "chromium-browser".

Answer (score -1):

**Install Google Chrome 48.0.2564.116 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus (LTS)**

Open a new Terminal window and type in the following commands:

**Download For Ubuntu 32 bit:**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

**Install:**

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

In addition, if you find you wish to:

**Download For Ubuntu 64 bit:**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Install:**

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**In case “dpkg” indicates missing dependencies, complete the installation by executing the following command:**

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

[Source](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/02/install-google-chrome-4802564116-on.html)

Comment: The link to i386 package doesn't work (404 Not Found). Please check your facts before posting.

Comment: Hhhhhmmmmmm, Google Chrome 48.0.2564.116 was released on Febuary 18th: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/stable-channel-update_18.html , well after the releases people are saying are no-longer supported, and the article specifically sites Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus (LTS) and the Google Chrome version mentioned in its walk-through... One wonders if we should have a list of known non-authoritative websites if the consensus among users runs contrary to the information thus presented...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Google Chrome still supports Linux; it just doesn't support 32-bit Linux anymore. 64-bit is fine and still being updated.